# Calculate the total time spent in a week

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I want to calculate the total time spent in a week (**the start of the week will be from a given date**).

Here the given date is `2020-06-23 15:30:00`. And the next week will start from 7 days after.

The duration of the activity will be calculated by the time gap between two rows for the same id if only the second is **less than an hour after the first**.

```
select t.UserName,
1 + datediff(second, '2020-06-23 15:30:00', CompletedOn) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 7) as week_num,
sum(datediff(minute, CompletedOn, next_ts)) as duration_minutes
from (select t.*,
lead(CompletedOn) over (partition by UserName order by CompletedOn) as next_ts
from #Results t
where t.CompletedOn >= '2020-06-23 15:30:00'
) t
where datediff(minute, CompletedOn, next_ts) < 60 and CompletedOn >='2020-06-23 15:30:00' and t.UserName = 'John B'
group by t.UserName, datediff(second, '2020-06-23 15:30:00', CompletedOn) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 7)
order by t.UserName, week_num;
```

The above query doesn't consider displaying the **week_num** if there is no entry for the date in the week, so it display the result as:

```
   UserName       | week_num |  duration_minutes
   ---------------|----------|------------------
   John B         |    1     |      38
   John B         |    2     |      10
   John B         |    3     |      0
   John B         |    5     |      0
```

However, I wanted the output as all the week number that falls up to the last date in the record.

```
   UserName       | week_num |  duration_minutes
   ---------------|----------|------------------
   John B         |    1     |      38
   John B         |    2     |      10
   John B         |    3     |      0
   John B         |    4     |      0
   John B         |    5     |      0
```

Some of the sample data:

```
       IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
        Truncate TABLE #Results
    else
        CREATE TABLE #Results
        (
            UserName varchar(20) not null,
            CompletedOn datetime not null
        )      
  
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-06-23T15:30:00'
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-06-23T15:31:00'
   --1 min
   
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-06-30T12:57:00'      
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-06-30T13:06:00'
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-06-30T13:34:00'
   --37 min 
   
   
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-06-30 15:31:00'      
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-06-30 15:33:00'
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-06-30 15:41:00'
   
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-06 08:41:00'      
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-07 14:29:00'
   
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-09 15:22:00'      
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-09 16:23:00'
   
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-21 15:34:00'      
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-21 17:00:00'
   
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-09 15:22:00'      
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-09 16:23:00'
   
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-21 15:34:00'      
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-21 17:00:00'
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-21 17:00:00'
   
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-23 06:34:00'      
 
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-23 08:28:00'
   INSERT INTO #Results (UserName, CompletedOn) 
   SELECT 'John B', '2020-07-23 08:28:00'
```

[Db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9bd7227da10ea6a4b5606a9e8377cc1e)

Comment: How does sample table `#Results` compare to `Logs`? And what is `UR.`? Please set up and test your [mcve] in sqlfiddle, db<>fiddle, rextester, or other online demo.

Comment: updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider joining to a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that generates pair matches of `UserName` and all subsequent `week_num` to a defined end point. Below uses 10 but can extend to say 52.

```
WITH pairs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT UserName, 1 AS week_num
    FROM #Results
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserName, week_num + 1
    FROM pairs 
    WHERE week_num < 10                 -- ADJUST ## AS NEEDED
),  sub AS (
    SELECT t.UserName
         , t.CompletedOn
         , LEAD(CompletedOn) OVER (PARTITION BY t.UserName ORDER BY t.CompletedOn) as next_ts
    FROM #Results t
    WHERE t.CompletedOn >= '2020-06-23 15:30:00'
), main AS (
    SELECT sub.UserName
         , 1 + DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020-06-23 15:30:00', sub.CompletedOn) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 7) AS week_num
         , SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, sub.CompletedOn, sub.next_ts)) AS duration_minutes
    FROM sub
    WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, sub.CompletedOn, sub.next_ts) < 60 
      AND sub.CompletedOn >='2020-06-23 15:30:00' 
      AND sub.UserName = 'John B'
    GROUP BY sub.UserName
           , DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2020-06-23 15:30:00', sub.CompletedOn) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 7)
)

SELECT pairs.UserName
     , pairs.week_num
     , ISNULL(main.duration_minutes, 0) AS duration_minutes
FROM pairs
LEFT JOIN main
   ON pairs.UserName = main.UserName
   AND pairs.week_num = main.week_num

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/QUXE49552)</kbd>

```
|    | UserName | week_num | duration_minutes |
|----|----------|----------|------------------|
| 1  | John B   | 1        | 38               |
| 2  | John B   | 2        | 10               |
| 3  | John B   | 3        | 0                |
| 4  | John B   | 4        | 0                |
| 5  | John B   | 5        | 0                |
| 6  | John B   | 6        | 0                |
| 7  | John B   | 7        | 0                |
| 8  | John B   | 8        | 0                |
| 9  | John B   | 9        | 0                |
| 10 | John B   | 10       | 0                |
```

Comment: why is the week up to 10 weeks? just need up to the date until the last records.

Comment: Once again, as explained, you can stretch it to however long needed such as 52 for year length. Hard-code to even 1,000 but be sure to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);` at the end to avoid default recursion limit. There are [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) (see link) to how dynamic you can make the recursive part of CTE.

Comment: yeah, I got that I can stretch the week but I wouldn't know up to when the week could last.

Comment: If you cannot set this up as a 1-year, 2-year, 5-year, etc. report, how about you extend to a very large number like 1,000 weeks and in outer query add a `WHERE pairs.week_num <= (SELECT MAX(week_num) FROM main)`. Estimate such a figure with current output. Another alternative is to build a separate large *pairs* table to replace recursive `pairs` CTE here. Ultimately, you are essentially asking to add *new* rows to query which needs to be sourced some way!